# Django: ValueError exception when assigning one-to-many member variable

Tags: django

I have two Django models, `Team` and `Player`, where `Player` has a many-to-one relationship with `Team`:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
```

I have created a `Team` object, and saved it in the SQL database:

```
my_team = Team(name = 'Django_FC')
my_team.save()
```

Now, I want to create a `Player` object, `my_player`, whose `team` is the `my_team` object that I just created. But I am outside the scope of where I created `my_team`, so I must load it from the database in order to assign it to `my_player`'s team. I have therefore tried the following:

```
the_team = Team.objects.filter(name = 'Django_FC')
my_player = Player(name = 'Mr_Python', team = the_team)
```

However, I get the following `ValueError` exception:

```
Cannot assign "[<Team: Django_FC>]": "Player.team" must be a "Team" instance.
```

Please can somebody explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `get()` instead of `filter()`:

```
the_team = Team.objects.get(name='Django_FC')
```

Quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get):

> `filter()` will always give you a `QuerySet`, even if only a single object
>   matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a
>   single element.
>
> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can
>   use the `get()` method on a Manager which returns the object directly.

Comment: @Karnivaurus exactly the same?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I think your solution worked actually! I had a different, but similar, exception, which I've solved now. Thanks!